# Adding + sign to exponent in matplotlib axes

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a log-log plot where the range goes from `10^-3` to `10^+3`. I would like values `≥10^0` to have a `+` sign in the exponent analogous to how values `<10^0` have a `-` sign in the exponent. Is there an easy way to do this in matplotlib?

I looked into `FuncFormatter` but it seems overly complex to achieve this and also I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to format the annotations for the tick-marks on the x and y axes like that?

Comment: @tokamak - For the moment actually only interested in the y-axis but it'd be nice to set both axes individually

Comment: Looking at the code which generates the tick marks https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/7d1a7c2e4637efba239ad3b984928c0175d45f98/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L803 it looks like there isn't an obvious way of changing it yourself. I guess a non optimal way would be to just create a modified version of that changing line 823.

Comment: @SimonGibbons, there's always a way to change things, you just need to know where to look! in this case, the OP already mentioned `FuncFormatter`, which is exactly the tool we need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a `FuncFormatter` from the `matplotlib.ticker` module. You need a condition on whether the tick's value is greater than or less than 1. So, if `log10(tick value)` is `>0`, then add the `+` sign in the label string, if not, then it will get its minus sign automatically.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

# sample data
x = y = np.logspace(-3,3)

# create a figure
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# plot sample data
ax.loglog(x,y)

# this is the function the FuncFormatter will use
def mylogfmt(x,pos):
    logx = np.log10(x) # to get the exponent
    if logx < 0:
        # negative sign is added automatically  
        return u"$10^{{{:.0f}}}$".format(logx)
    else:
        # we need to explicitly add the positive sign
        return u"$10^{{+{:.0f}}}$".format(logx)

# Define the formatter
formatter = ticker.FuncFormatter(mylogfmt)

# Set the major_formatter on x and/or y axes here
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Some explanation of the format string:

```
"$10^{{+{:.0f}}}$".format(logx)
```

the double braces `{{` and `}}` are passed to `LaTeX`, to signify everything within them should be raised as an exponent. We need double braces, because the single braces are used by python to contain the format string, in this case `{:.0f}`. For more explanation of format specifications, see the [docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), but the TL;DR for your case is we are formatting a float with a precision of 0 decimal places (i.e. printing it essentially as an integer); the exponent is a float in this case because `np.log10` returns a float. (one could alternatively convert the output of `np.log10` to an int, and then format the string as an int - just a matter of your preference which you prefer).

Comment: Ok thx, i am going with this... can you explain the format of `{{:.0f}}` i am guessing the excessive brackets are used to escape, but what exactly does `:.0f` do?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you mean:

```
def fmt(y, pos):
    a, b = '{:.2e}'.format(y).split('e')
    b = int(b)
    if b >= 0:
      format_example = r'$10^{+{}}$'.format(b)
    else:
      format_example = r'$10^{{}}$'.format(b)
    return
```

Then use `FuncFormatter`, e.g. for a colorbar: `plt.colorbar(name_of_plot,ticks=list_with_tick_locations, format = ticker.FuncFormatter(fmt))`. I think you have to import `import matplotlib.ticker as ticker`.

Regards